# All vertices with out-degree greater than 10

Tags: titan, gremlin

In Titan graph database, using gremlin, I want all the vertices whose out-degree is greater than 10.

How to do it?

Something like this doesn't work :

```
g.V().has(outE().count()>10)
```

Help please!!

Answer (score 3):

You need something like this:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().filter(outE().count().is(gt(10)))
==>v[1]
==>v[4]
```